# Makefile: Unable to add .h files from folder using a .mk file

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to link a .h file from a folder into a Makefile using a .mk file. Folder with .h file (include) is in the same folder as Makefile.

When I run from terminal: make memory.o or make memory.o PLATFORM=MSP432 I get the following error

make: *** No rule to make target '-I./include', needed by 'memory.o'. Stop.

My .mk folder looks like this:

```
# Add your Source files to this variable
SOURCES =            \
    ./main.c   \
    ./memory.c      

# Add your include paths to this variable
INCLUDES =-I./include
```

My Make file looks like this:

```
include sources.mk

# Platform Overrides
PLATFORM = 

# Architectures Specific Flags
LINKER_FILE = msp432p401r.lds
CPU = cortex-m0plus
ARCH = thumb
SPECS = nosys.specs

# Compiler Flags and Defines
CC = arm-none-eabi-gcc
LD = arm-none-eabi-ld
TARGET= c1m2
LDFLAGS = -Wl, -Map=$(TARGET).map -T $(LINKER_FILE)
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -g -O0 -std=c99 -mcpu=$(CPU) -m$(ARCH) --specs=$(SPECS)
CPPFLAGs = 

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),MSP)
    CPU=cortex-m4
    CC=arm-none-eabi-gcc
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),HOST)
    CC=gcc
endif

OBJS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)

%.o : %.c $(INCLUDES)
    $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@

.PHONY: build
build: all

.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGET).out

$(TARGET).out: $(OBJS) $(INCLUDES)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET).out $(TARGET).map
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't put `$(INCLUDES)` as a prerequisite of your .o file.  This is not right:

```
%.o : %.c $(INCLUDES)
        $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@
```

`INCLUDES` contains options that need to be passed to the compiler (`-I...`).  Prerequisites of targets need to be files that are used during the build.  I suppose you want this:

```
%.o : %.c
        $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@
```